# Why is Prettier not formating one of the .ts files?

Tags: typescript, prettier

In Visual Studio Code, according to the Prettier logs, formatting has completed but the file in question hasn’t changed.

```sh
["INFO" - 8:03:25 AM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/path/to/project/src/test/index.ts",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "printWidth": 80,
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
["INFO" - 8:03:25 AM] Formatting completed in 466.936538ms.
```

File content before and after it is saved (excerpt)

```js
'use strict'

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
```

Expected file content after it is saved (excerpt)

```js
"use strict"

import dotenv from "dotenv"
```

Here’s my Prettier section in `package.json`.

```
"prettier": {
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "printWidth": 80,
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

All other files in the project appear to be formatted correctly when they are saved.

Comment: Interesting, I think it might have something to do with the fact the file has over 2,000 lines... investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit!

Visual Studio Code has an `editor.formatOnSaveTimeout` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) that is set to `750` milliseconds by default.

> Timeout in milliseconds after which the formatting that is run on file
>   save is cancelled.

That wasn’t enough time for Prettier to format my file which has over 2,000 lines.

I switched `editor.formatOnSaveTimeout` to `1500` and it worked!