# Inspect at see why prettier ignores one file (that is not listed in the .prettierignore)

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, prettier

Prettier seems to be working just fine for all other files except this one file that I can't format without forcing it.

Tried with `npx prettier --write .` and the vscode extension `format with..`. The only way to format the file is to `Format with (force)`.

Is there a way the inspect why a file is ignored by prettier?

---

[Why is Prettier not formating one of the .ts files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897249/why-is-prettier-not-formating-one-of-the-ts-files) the file is only 700 lines so don't think its a speed issue.